# Watchdog timer > 60s in linux embedded

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, busybox, watchdog

I am using linux watchdog driver /dev/watchdog on a linux embedded system with busy box as user space tools. I want to trigger the watchdog from C/C++ code, which works fine for timeouts up to 60s:

```
watchdogFD = open( "/dev/watchdog", O_WRONLY );
int timeout = 60;
ioctl( watchdogFD, WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT, &timeout )
```

However for larger intervals the timeout is accepted, but the watchdog is triggered already after 60s.

The linux watchdog deamon offers a --force parameter to set timeouts larger than 60s (see https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog). However the busy box watchdog deamon does not offer this (see https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/miscutils/watchdog.c?id=1572f520ccfe9e45d4cb9b18bb7b728eb2bbb571).

Does anyone have a suggestion how to use the same --force option when controlling watchdog using ioctl? Thanks :)

Comment: It's entirely possible that the hardware watchdog timer on your system simply doesn't support timeouts longer than 60s.

Comment: @larsks are you implying, that if hardware support is given, ioctl( WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT) with a value > 60s actually should work?

Comment: No, the opposite: that maybe there is a hardware limitation in the length of the watchdog timer.  I don't know that's the case or not; I was simply speculating.

Comment: If the physical hardware doesn't support it then the driver can kick the watchdog more frequently (without a user space kick) to extend the timeout.    I don't think you want a system where interrupts can't work for 60s so driver extension is okay?  I think you need to print 'timeout' after the call.  Why pass a reference and not a value?  Did someone change it?  Also try to nice the watchdog process and/or non-critical GUI or whatever is taking up 60s (which is quite insane).  It maybe what some non-busybox daemon does.

Comment: @artlessnoise a driver extension is OK for me, where do I find such an extension? The 'timeout' variable is passed as reference, as the ioctl call will set the really used timeout in case the driver needs to adapt values (so with my hardware timeout is set to 60 when it was larger before).

Comment: Does `dmesg` contain anything WD timeout related? If not reading the driver docs and source as well as the WD module data sheet may be the only way to find out about accepted values.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers.
What I originally wanted to do is trigger the watchdog using ioctl from my application. Why do I need a timeout > 60s? Because I have a single threaded application that does some file decryption that takes longer then 60s.
The limitation in my case seems to be the hardware driver, which does not accept intervals larger than 60s.
I ended using the userspace watchdog daemon, which checks my application using a pidfile, see https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog

Answer (score 0):

It seems the busybox watchdog daemon you link to is very simple compared to the usual Linux one from here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/watchdog/code/ci/master/tree/

The --force option for the Linux daemon (above) is to override the sanity checks on the polling interval versus the hardware time-out used. It will not change any limits a specific hardware driver/timer has to offer.

Typically the choice of hardware time-out is in the 10-60 second range, depending on how long you can tolerate a major fault (like a kernel panic) persisting for. Then the watchdog daemon that feeds the timer has to poll at an interval that is at least a few seconds shorter so nothing timers out unexpectedly. Between polls it uses nanosleep() so gives up its CPU time, and so the system load for the daemon is proportional to the polling rate and the type of tests that are run.

Without any tests all you protect against is a major fault killing either the daemon or kernel, so usually you should be checking for something else that is essential for normal operations (e.g. a specific process being alive, files being updated, test script can be run, etc) to get the most benefit.